# How do I write the terraform for an aws_autoscaling_policy for Step Scaling to set capacity units?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-auto-scaling

The terraform for StepScaling is fairly limited for this resource. It includes terraform for removing and adding capacities, however, I am trying to set a number of capacities based on the lower and upper bounds of my Cloudwatch metric.

Essentially, I am trying to recreate and write up this resource (Dynamic Scaling Policy on Auto Scaling group) in terraform:

```
Policy type: Step Scaling
Scaling policy name: scale-out
CloudWatch alarm: my-sqs-alarm
Take the action: Set to
1 capacity units when 1 <= ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible < 6
2 capacity units when 6 <= ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible < 11
3 capacity units when 11 <= ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible < +infinity
```

This is what I have so far:

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_policy" "scale-out" {
  name                   = "scale-out"
  policy_type = "StepScaling"
  autoscaling_group_name = aws_autoscaling_group.autoscaler.name
```

How do I recreate my steps from the AWS console in terraform?

[image: From AWS Console:]

Comment: Does this work without Terraform?

Comment: @MarkoE yes it works if I create it in the console, I have attached an image to show the console options.

Comment: Ok, so that's Step Scaling and not Target Tracking?

Comment: Yes, step scaling

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to set:

```
adjustment_type           = "ExactCapacity"
```

Then I got the configuration I wanted by writing:

```
step_adjustment {
    scaling_adjustment          = 1
    metric_interval_lower_bound = 0
    metric_interval_upper_bound = 5
  }

  step_adjustment {
    scaling_adjustment          = 2
    metric_interval_lower_bound = 5
    metric_interval_upper_bound = 10
  }

  step_adjustment {
    scaling_adjustment          = 3
    metric_interval_lower_bound = 10
  }
```